# How do I know whether a private network is using proof of work or stake or authorize?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, contract-deployment

I know there are three types of protocol proof of work or stake or authorize, I am using `geth --datadir data/node1 --http --dev --http.corsdomain "*" --http.api web3,eth,debug,personal,net,miner --allow-insecure-unlock --mine` to deploy a private network with one node. How do I know whether it is stake, authorize or work?

I am able to deploy contract to this network without waiting for any seconds. But I think in case of proof of work, the node needs to solve a math pazzle issue before deploying a block. why does it happen so quick on private network?